# How to delay ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask first execution

Tags: reactiveui

I have an App made with Xamarin.Forms and ReactiveUI.
Picture a View in this App where you have a kind of dropdown (actually a button that push another view where the user can filter and select one option) and when this "dropdown" is changed, I need to reload a list based on its value.

This "dropdown" won't start with some value, I need to make a async request, grab a value and then update the view.

The problem is, when I'm creating the command to load the documents:

```
LoadAllDocuments = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string, IEnumerable<Document>>(_ => m_service.GetAllDocumentsByTodoListAsync(SelectedTodoList.Id), canLoadAll, m_scheduler);
```

I need the Id from the SelectedToDoList, but this will be null at this point.

There's any way to delay this first execution of a command? Or maybe there's a better workflow to solve this?

Here is a sniped on how I'm doing it right now. Let me know if more information is needed.

```
LoadAllDocuments = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string, IEnumerable<Document>>(_ => m_service.GetAllDocumentsByTodoListAsync(SelectedTodoList.Id), canLoadAll, m_scheduler);
ChangeToDoListCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<DocumentListViewModel, bool>(vm => this.PushPageFromCacheAsync<ToDoListViewModel>((model) => model.ParentViewModel = this));

this.WhenActivated((CompositeDisposable disposables) =>
{
    SelectedItem = null;

    var SelectedTodoListChanged =
        this
            .WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedTodoList)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Publish();

    SelectedTodoListChanged
        .Where(x => x == null)
        .Subscribe(async _ => SelectedTodoList = await viewService.GetMyToDoListByVaultAsync(RuntimeContext.Current.VaultId))
        .DisposeWith(disposables);

    SelectedTodoListChanged
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .InvokeCommand(LoadAllDocuments)
        .DisposeWith(disposables);

    SelectedTodoListChanged.Connect();

    LoadAllDocuments
        .ObserveOn(m_scheduler)
        .SubscribeOn(m_scheduler)
        .Subscribe(list => AddViewsToList(list.ToList()))
        .DisposeWith(disposables);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to ensure `Id` is not `null` before calling `InvokeCommand`:

```
SelectedTodoListChanged
    .Where(x => x?.Id != null)
    .InvokeCommand(LoadAllDocuments)
    .DisposeWith(disposables);
```

Perhaps a better option is to bake this knowledge into the command itself. Since `InvokeCommand` respects the execution window of the command (as of RxUI 7, that is), if your command's `CanExecute` is currently `false` then `InvokeCommand` will not actually invoke your command:

```
var canLoadAllDocuments = this
    .WhenAnyValue(x => x.SelectedTodoList?.Id)
    .Select(id => id != null);
LoadAllDocuments = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string, IEnumerable<Document>>(
    _ => m_service.GetAllDocumentsByTodoListAsync(SelectedTodoList.Id), canLoadAll,
    canLoadAllDocuments,
    m_scheduler);
```

Now you can do this:

```
SelectedTodoListChanged
    .InvokeCommand(LoadAllDocuments)
    .DisposeWith(disposables);
```

Comment: I had a misconception that the command would be called right away when I CreateFromTask, but I didn't want it. But what was a really happening was that since command won't run unit you call them, I had another place invoking it. Your answer helped to find this problem and made the code better with the canLoadAllDocuments.